# Trying to push/unshift an element right after POST with AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am successfully adding an element to my RESTful Rails API (it's an experimental note-taking App) but I cannot append it to the list of existing elements on the page. I don't care If it's unshift or push, I just can't update the list.

**NoteController.js**

```
var app = angular.module('notepadApp');

app.controller('NoteController',
    ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Note',
        function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, Note) {
            $scope.notes = Note.query();

            //Destroy method for deleting a forum
        $scope.destroy = function(index) {
            //Tell the server to remove the object
            Note.remove({id: $scope.notes[index].id}, function() {
                //If successful, remove it from our collection
                $scope.notes.splice(index, 1);
            });
        }
        }]
);

app.controller('NoteShowController',
    ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Note',
        function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, Note) {
            $scope.note = Note.get({id: $routeParams.id});
        }]
);

app.controller('NoteCreateController',
    ['$scope', 'Note', '$routeParams', function($scope, Note, $routeParams) {
        $scope.notes = Note.query();
        $scope.newNote = {};
        $scope.createNote = function() {

            var newNote = new Note($scope.note)
            newNote.$save();
            $scope.notes.push(newNote);
            $scope.newNote = '';
            $scope.errors = '';

        }
}]);
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('notepadApp', [ 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'templates', 'ng-rails-csrf'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',      { controller: 'NoteController',  templateUrl: 'notes/index.html' })
            .when('/notes', { controller: 'NoteController',  templateUrl: 'notes/index.html' })
            .when('/notes/new', { controller: 'NoteCreateController',  templateUrl: 'notes/new.html' })
            .when('/notes/:id', { controller: 'NoteShowController',  templateUrl: 'notes/show.html' })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

**models.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('notepadApp');

app.factory('Note', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/v1/notes/:id', { id: "@id" });
}]);
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="ui divided grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="four wide column">
      <div class="ui divided padded items" ng-controller="NoteController">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat='note in notes'>
          <div class="content">
            <h4 class="ui header">
              <a href="#/notes/{{note.id}}">{{note.title}}</a>
            </h4>
            <a ng-click="destroy($index)" href=""><i class="ui icon trash"></i></a>
            <div class="extra">
              <div ng-repeat='tag in note.tag_list'>
                {{ tag }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="twelve wide column">
      <div ng-view="ng-view"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h2 class='ui dividing header'>
  Create a new note
</h2>

<form ng-submit="createNote()" class="ui form">

    <!-- The control-group, control-label, and controls classes are Bootstrap specific -->
    <div class="field">
        <label>Title:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="note.title"/>
        <div ng-repeat="error in errors.title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Tags:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="note.tag_list"/>
        <div ng-repeat="error in errors.tag_list"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Description:</label>
        <textarea ng-model="note.description"/>
        <div ng-repeat="error in errors.description"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <button class="ui small blue button" type="submit"> Create </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Any ideas will be appreciated :)

Comment: Is Note a service? If so, please share the code...

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: Firstly, you don't provide much informateion. Looks like you don't have anything, which start AngularJS $digest cycle. Try to push new not in $scope.$apply:`$scope.$apply(function () { // there });`

Comment: As he uses `$save`, `newNote` should be a resource object, in which case it will trigger the digest cycle for him. Just a guess though.

Comment: @tasseKATT we can only assume there. We need more information. May be you are right

Comment: Sorry guys, I've edited and included all the code I've got for now.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav code added

Comment: I think I miss somethink. How do you expect `var newNote = new Note($scope.note)` to work? Note reutrns `$resource`. Also, you do `newNote.$save();`. How this expected to work?

Comment: I think you should use resource factory like this: `Note.get(queryParameters, function onSuccess() {});`

Comment: By the way, don't use both `ng-controller` and controller in routes, you will get two instances.

Comment: I will be very happy to accept a complete reply.. I don't really get it with random suggestions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your push inside a promise instead.

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('notepadApp');

app.factory('Note', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/v1/notes/:id', { id: "@id" }, {
    create: {
      method: 'POST'
    }
  });
}]);

app.controller('NoteCreateController',
    ['$scope', 'Note', '$routeParams', function($scope, Note,   $routeParams) {
        $scope.notes = Note.query();
        $scope.newNote = {};
        $scope.createNote = function() {

            Note.create($scope.note).$promise.then(function (savedNote) {
              $scope.notes.push(savedNote);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              // handle any errors here
            });

        };
}]);
```

**UPDATE:**

I still recommend using promises instead of the $save convenience method, but it looks like you have a scope issue. Your ng-repeat is using NoteController, but your view to create new notes is using NoteCreateController. From the looks of it, the notes object on the $scope you're pushing to isn't the scope NoteController is using. The solution would be to share a single $scope and do your work there.

Updated code example:

```
var app = angular.module('notepadApp');

app.controller('NoteController',
    ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Note', 'ShareNoteScope', 
        function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, Note, ShareNoteScope) {

        $scope.notes = Note.get().$promise.then(function () {
          ShareNoteScope.setScope($scope);
        });

            //Destroy method for deleting a forum
        $scope.destroy = function(index) {
            //Tell the server to remove the object
            Note.remove({id: $scope.notes[index].id}, function() {
                //If successful, remove it from our collection
                $scope.notes.splice(index, 1);
            });
        }
        }]
);

app.controller('NoteShowController',
    ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Note',
        function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, Note, ShareNoteScope) {
            if (ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes) {
              ShareNoteScope.getScope().forEach(function (note) {
                if (note.id === $routeParams.id) {
                  $scope.note = note;
                }
              });
            } else {
              $scope.note = Note.get({id: $routeParams.id});
            }
        }]
);

app.controller('NoteCreateController',
    ['$scope', 'Note', '$routeParams', 'ShareNoteScope', function($scope, Note, $routeParams, ShareNoteScope) {
        $scope.notes = ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes;
        $scope.newNote = {};
        $scope.createNote = function() {

            Note.create($scope.note).$promise.then(function (newNote) {
              ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes.push(newNote);
              $scope.newNote = '';
              $scope.errors = '';
            });

        }
}]);

app.factory('Note', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/v1/notes/:id', { id: "@id" }, {
    get: {
      method: 'GET'
    },
    create: {
      method: 'POST'
    }
  });
}]);

app.factory('ShareNoteScope', function (Note) {
  var $scope;
  return {
    setScope: function (scope) {
      $scope = scope;
    },
    getScope: function () {
      return $scope;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It POSTs successfully but again, it doesn't add (push or unshift) the item to the list without pressing F5.

Comment: Did you try tossing `$scope.notes.push(savedNote)` into `$scope.$apply(function(){$scope.notes.push(savedNote)})` ?

Comment: Yes, there is no change.

Comment: Are you sure your post is even returning a note?

Comment: absolutely, I see it in firebug

Comment: It looks like you have a scope issue. Your ng-repeat is using NoteController, but your ng-repeat is using NoteCreateController. From the looks of it, the notes object on the $scope you're pushing to isn't the scope NoteController is using. The solution would be to extract the $scope.notes from the NoteController and put it in a service, and have both the $scope.notes in the NoteController and the NoteCreateController reference that single object.

Comment: can you write an example please?

Comment: now it doesn't save anything when creating a new note and also there is an error in firebug about .foreach which is not existing :(

Comment: Probably because the ShareNoteScope.setScope was firing before Note.query() finished. I fixed it by putting your Note.get in a promise.

Comment: This error : `Error: ShareNoteScope.getScope(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: This error `Error: ShareNoteScope.getScope(...).forEach is not a function` persists... do you have any idea ?

Comment: You should be doing `ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes.forEach`, not `ShareNoteScope.getScope().forEach`. You forgot the notes property, it looks like.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981664/indexof-deletes-the-wrong-item-in-angularjs#33981664