# indexOf deletes the wrong item in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building a note taking application (something like a blog actually with different terms like post=note etc.) to practise my skills in AngularJS and Rails.

There is a sidebar on the left (controller Sidebar.js) which fetches all items form the Rails API and ng-repeats them to a list.

By clicking on one of them, the show.html renders inside ng-show on the right. The show view, has a link that lets you delete the item and then splices it from the sidebar on the left. After much blood, sweat and tears I believe I made it, except one detail: After deletion(=> destroy()) of the item, the wrong index gets deleted from the sidebar. I've tried to make it work with indexOf and then I console.logged the index - it always appears to be -1.

To share the same array of note objects I created a service that does that with a getter and a setter.

How can I delete the right item from the sidebar?

**show.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <h3>{{ note.title }}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <button type="button" ng-click="destroy(note)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="note-description">
  {{ note.description }}
  <br>
</div>
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
var app = angular.module('notepadApp');

app.controller('SidebarController',
  ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Note', 'ShareNoteScope',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, Note, ShareNoteScope) {

    $scope.notes = Note.query(function (){
      ShareNoteScope.setScope($scope.notes);
    });


    $scope.getClass = function (path) {
      if ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) === path) {
        return 'active';
      } else {
        return '';
      }
    }
  }]
);
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked" ng-controller="SidebarController">
  <li ng-repeat="note in notes.notes | orderBy: '-created_at'" class="note-li">
    <a href="/notes/{{note.id}}" ng-class="getClass('/notes/{{note.id}}')"
       class="" >
    {{ note.title }}
    </a>
    <div ng-repeat="tag in note.tags">
      <div class="label">{{ tag }}</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**NoteCtrl.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('notepadApp');

app.controller('NoteController',
  ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {

  }]
);

app.controller('NoteShowController',
  ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Note', 'ShareNoteScope',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, Note, ShareNoteScope) {

      if ($routeParams.id) {
        Note.get({id: $routeParams.id}, function(note){
          $scope.note = note.note;
        });
      }
      else {
        $scope.note = ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes[0].id;
      }

      //Destroy method for deleting a note
      $scope.destroy = function(note) {
        Note.remove({id: note.id}, function() {
          var index = ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes.indexOf(note);
          console.log(index);
          ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes.splice(index, 1);
        });
        $location.path('/notes');
      }
  }]
);

app.controller('NoteCreateController',
  ['$scope', 'Note', '$routeParams', '$location','ShareNoteScope',
    function($scope, Note, $routeParams, $location, ShareNoteScope) {

    $scope.notes = ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes;

    $scope.newNote = {};
    $scope.createNote = function() {
      Note.create($scope.note, function (newNote) {
        $scope.notes.unshift(newNote.note);
        $scope.newNote = '';
        $scope.errors = '';
        $location.path('/notes/'+newNote.note.id);
      });
    }


}]);
```

**models.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('notepadApp');

app.factory('Note', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/notes/:id', { id: "@id" }, {
    get: {
      method: 'GET'
    },
    query: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: false
    },
    create: {
      method: 'POST'
    }
  });
}]);

app.factory('ShareNoteScope', function (Note) {
  var $scope;
  return {
    setScope: function (scope) {
      $scope = scope;
    },
    getScope: function () {
      return $scope;
    }
  }
});
```

**ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes** contents

```
$$hashKey

    "object:5"
created_at

    "2015-11-29T09:07:18.614Z"
description

    null
id

    130
tags

    []
title

    "5345"
updated_at

    "2015-11-29T09:07:18.614Z"
user_id

    1
```

Comment: Where is the `remove` function in your `Note` `factory`?

Comment: @Arg0n I suppose it is picked automatically? It deletes the element successfully, it just removes the wrong index from the sidebar list. Do you think I should add it to the factory too ?

Comment: @benams What? No, provide link to a fiddle in CONJUNCTION with the code. Never post only a link.

Comment: @Radolino Oh, i've not used `$resource`, so that may be correct. What is `ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes` and `note` when the code reaches the callback?

Comment: @Arg0n no problem.. what do you mean what is? What type? If yes, it's an array and note is an object. Is there any chance the wrong item may be spliced because I order the list ? If I delete, then refresh the page, I see the right item removed.

Comment: @Radolino I mean, how do they look? Can you show the contents of the array, and what the object looks like? If `index` is always  -1, i suspect the error is in this part of the code.

Comment: @Arg0n I added it, the index always is -1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96460/discussion-between-arg0n-and-radolino).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We went to the bottom of this in the chat. And the problem probably had to do with `note` not referencing an `object` in `ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes`. So to get a correct reference, we used `filter` in this case:

JavaScript

```
$scope.destroy = function(note) { 
    Note.remove({id: note.id}, function() { 
        var res = ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes.filter(function(el){ 
            return el.id == note.id; 
        }); 
        note = res[0]; 
        var index = ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes.indexOf(note); 
        console.log(index); 
        ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes.splice(index, 1); 
    }); 
    $location.path('/notes'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass $index in destroy method along with note object

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <h3>{{ note.title }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <button type="button" ng-click="destroy(note,$index)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="note-description">
    {{ note.description }}
    <br>
</div>


  $scope.destroy = function(note, $index) {
    Note.remove({id: note.id}, function() {
      ShareNoteScope.getScope().notes.splice($index, 1);
    });
    $location.path('/notes');
  }
```

Try this

Comment: I already tried that, the $index appears to be "undefined" and same behaviour seems to occur.